# how to remove duplicate values from my select dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, html.dropdownlistfor

this is my jsp code:

```
<form method="post" action="" >
    <table style="width: 100%;border: 0px;border-spacing: 0px;padding: 0px;">
    <tr>

    <td style="height: 28px; font-size: 14px; width:80px; ">Select State :</td>

    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 10px; width: 450px;">  
        <select name="city"  onchange="Consituteshow(this.value)">  
                    <option value="">Andhra Pradesh</option>  
                    <%
                                            Statement stmt=null;
                                            DBconnection db=new DBconnection();
                                            Connection con=db.dbConn();
                                            try{
                                            stmt = con.createStatement();  
                                            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select distinct StateID,State from election_history;");
                                            while(rs.next())
                                            {
                      %>

                                           <option value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  

                     <%}%>

      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

above is my jsp code and in this code i have given 'Andhra Pradesh' as default name.due to this inside dropdown list 'Andhra Pradesh' is printed twice.Is there any way to remove it???

Comment: Could you show your actual HTML, not the script used to generate that HTML?

Comment: so why don't you provide the value for the `Andhra Pradesh` option?

Comment: why is my question downvoted??can anyone explain me?

Comment: how were you able to answer my question if it was unclear??can anyone reply to me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if name is "Andhra Pradesh" and if it is then select the option with `selected="selected"`

```
 <!-- no default option here -->
 <option value=""></option> 

     <%
     while(rs.next()){   
        if( !rs.getString(2).equals("Andhra Pradesh") ){
            <option  value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
        }else{
            <option selected="selected" value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
        }
    }
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either write query

```
  select distinct StateID,State from election_history where State != 'Andhra Pradesh'
```

or you may need to use `jQuery.unique()` method

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything inside the while-statement in:

see this:

`if(rs.getString(2) !="Andhra Pradesh") { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select name="city"  onchange="Consituteshow(this.value)">  
                <%   
  Statement stmt=null;
  DBconnection db=new DBconnection(); 
  Connection con=db.dbConn();
   try{  
    stmt = con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select distinct StateID,State from election_history;");
    while(rs.next()){
                 if(!rs.getString(2).equals("Andhra Pradesh")){
                  %>
            <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
                 <%}else{%>
<option selected='selected' value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
    <%}
}%></select>
```